# Query does not use index seek

Tags: t-sql

I have a table say Table1 which has two columns

```
ID       Field1
-------  -------------
INT      VARCHAR(MAX)
```

The table has approx. 100,000 entries
and ID is primary key and has unique index on column 'Field1'. I run following query

```
SELECT T11.ID FROM Table1 T11
INNER JOIN dbo.MyFunc() T22
ON T11.Field1 = T22.ElementValue
```

The above query has high I/O cost. It does index scan on Field1 of Table1 but does not use Index seek. MyFunc is a user
defined function which returns a table variable of schema (ElementValue VARCHAR(MAX)). Here for simplicity purposes I skipped the variables passed to MyFunc. But if I run following query, it will be fast and use Index seek

```
SELECT T11.ID FROM Table1 T11
WHERE T11.Field1 = 'Test'
```

MyFunc also returns 'Test' as table variable of single col and single row.

Please note that I cannot avoid using MyFunc. it has some reusable code which is used in no. of stored procedures.

Please suggest any alternative to make it fast.

**EDIT:** I have found where the problem was. Actually it was a data mismatch. In MyFunc I used NVARCHAR but Field1 was VARCHAR. When I changed NVARCHAR to VARCHAR, Query optimizer picked the Index properly

Comment: Will dbo.MyFunc() always return only one row?

Comment: It can have multiple rows. Now the problem is resolved, how to close or mark this question as closed?

Comment: You can add your finding as an answer yourself and mark that answer as the correct one. There might be some time limits before you can do that. Or you can delete the question.

Answer (score 0):

if myfunc() always returns one row, maybe you could do something like ...
`select @myvar = elementvalue from dbo.myfunc()`
`select t11.id from table1 t11 where t11.field1 = @myvar`

Comment: It can have multiple rows but always single col. I have found where the problem was. Actually it was a data mismatch. In MyFunc I used NVARCHAR but Field1 was VARCHAR. When I changed NVARCHAR to VARCHAR, Query optimizer picked the Index properly.